# django tutorial part 1 (p.choice_set.all() returns in reverse order)

Tags: python, django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

I am following the Django tutorial and near the end of part 1 where p.choice_set.all() is called I get the display in reverse order.

For example I get: Just hacking again, The Sky, Not much
Instead of: Not much, The sky, Just hacking again

Any idea why I get reverse order?  I typed it in the same order as the tutorial indicated.

I am running with PostgreSQL.

Comment: You want to order by which field? Clearly in both cases it is not ordering by `choice_text`. If no ordering is given the default is `id`

Comment: This part of the tutorial:

# And vice versa: Poll objects get access to Choice objects.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: The sky>, <Choice: Just hacking again>]

I get that backwards^.....Just hacking again, The Sky, Not much

Comment: Can it be a database issue or quirk?  It displays in reverse. Perhaps the guide is not up to date or they are running it against another db

Comment: FYI: you can order by any field your self `p.choice_set.all().order_by('choice_text')`. I have no idea about this odd behaviour which you have mentioned.

Comment: Is the tutorial wrong then? Trying to find out why the tutorial gives one and I get another result

Comment: The tutorial is... limited.

Comment: Have you added the choices in the db in same order as done in tutorial?

Comment: Yes word for word exact.  Odd quirk really

Comment: It is ordering by `id` descending may be in your model do you have any default ordering specified? e.g. `ordering = ['-id',]` in model `Meta` class.

Comment: I am using the models.py example from earlier in the tutorial.
I see nothing about ordering in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't explicitly do an `order_by()` there's no guarantee which order the results will be returned in.

Not sure about PostgreSQL, but for MySQL, in practice, if you're only selecting a subset of rows based on some indexed column, it'll order by that index, but if you're selecting every row, it'll use a table scan and return the results in the order in which they're stored on disk.

With regards to disk order, if you've ever deleted a row, then it'll try to fill in the space used by that row when you next insert a row, so if you had...

```
ID   Name
1    Bob
2    Fred
3    Jim
```

...then delete the first row, then add in a new one, you get...

```
ID   Name
4    Jeff
2    Fred
3    Jim
```

...at which point a `SELECT * FROM my_table` will return them in the order 4, 2, 3, whereas a `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 1` will (probably) return them in the order 2, 3, 4.

Comment: So there is no guarantee and we can safely say this is just the way PostgreSQL works.  Very detained insight.  Thanks.

No guarantee. Hmm.

Comment: @klandshome It's not necessarily the way PostgreSQL *always* works - it might just be for that particular case. If you drop and recreate the table, you might get it in a different order.

Comment: @klandshome See also [this thread](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/default-ordering-of-query-result-are-they-always-guarantee-td1928356.html).

Comment: "An you're right. It's not guaranted. The only guaranted way is to use 
ORDER BY your_column."

I guess that is just how it works.  Very peculiar.  Thanks for educating.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation:

You can order fields by `order_by()`, if you don't use it it will be ordered by id.And thats why you are getting revere order.

You can check it by simple for loop:

```
for item in p.choice_set.all():
    print item.id
```

Thanks

Comment: The default order is by id ascending not descending

Comment: It is ordering by ID.  That much we know.
I ran your loop and it printed in reverse... 15 14